# Compile FFTW for ARM

Tags: timer, makefile, cross-compiling, fftw

I am trying to compile the FFTW library to be used on a ARM processor, but when compiling the library I get the following errors:

```
timer.c:89:2: error: #error "timer not defined"
#error "timer not defined"
^
timer.c:119:1: error: unknown type name 'mytime'
static mytime t0[BENCH_NTIMERS];
```

To create the Makefile, I use the provided configure file, and use it this way:

```
./configure --enable-float --with-slow-timer --host=i686-pc-linux-gnu --enable-single --enable-neon "CC=arm-xilinx-eabi-gcc -mcpu=cortex-a9 -mfloat-abi=softfp"
```

What can be causing this error? Is there a way to solve them without messing with the code?

Thanks

Comment: Added --disable-fortran to avoid a warning there appeared while doing the configure, but the problem persists

Answer (score 0):

as far as i know a cortex-a9 always has a timer unit. So i guess it has a cycle counter as mentioned in the reference of fftw3. Maybe u just dont use the slow-timer option which is worse in this case anyway.

Comment: I have already tried to use the configure without the --with-slow-timer option, but I keep getting the exact same error.

Answer (score 0):

You indicate `--host=i686-pc-linux-gnu` but say you are cross compiling for an ARM processor.  Try using `--host=arm-linux-gnueabi`